# Issue with the "U" (update) part of CRUD in reducers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reducers

I've been Working on redux-less CRUD project. Creating a categories list using contextAPI/hooks in combination. I have succeed, the "CR and D" (Create, Read and Delete) parts, but struggling with "U" (update) part, I couldn't get this to work after submit for update change.

Starting with how I did with the reducer components...

**reducer.js**

```js
import uniqid from 'uniqid';

export const categoryReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_CATEGORY':
            return [
                ...state,
                {
                    id: uniqid(),
                    name: action.name,
                    suffix: action.suffix
                }
            ];

       //**MY ISSUES**
        case 'UPDATE_CATEGORY':
            return (
                state.findIndex(item => item.id === action.id),
                state.slice(0, action.id, action.name, action.suffix)
            );
        case 'REMOVE_CATEGORY':
            return state.filter(item => item.id !== action.id);
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

the `'ADD_CATEGORY'` and `'DELETE_CATEGORY'` can be ignored since I don't have issues. The `'UPDATE_CATEGORY'` feel a little sketchy to me, I have feeling the syntax is incorrect. From my understanding, in order to make update changes. An selected item need to be scanned from array into matched id. Once the id is matched, The changes can be updated after submit. And I am not sure I could figure out how to add that syntax.

Now the The Edit Form component with dispatch inside `handleSubmit` function...

**EditCategoryForm.js**

```js
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';

//context
import { CategoryContext } from '../contexts/categoryContext';

function EditCategoryForm() {
    const { dispatch } = useContext( CategoryContext);

/*Not not get this to work */
    const handleSubmit = (e, name, suffix) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch({
            type: 'EDIT_CATEGORY',
            name,
            suffix
        });
     };

    const handleChange = e => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setInputValue(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }));
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <h1>Edit</h1>
            <input
                type="text"
                name="name"
                value={inputValue.name}
                onChange={handleChange}
            />
            <input
                type="text"
                name="suffix"
                value={inputValue.suffix}
                onChange={handleChange}
            />
            <button>Submit Change</button>
            <button onClick={() => setEditing(false)}>Cancel</button>
        </form>
    );
}

export default EditCategoryForm;
```

Again, I believe, the syntax have been implemented wrong. The goal is to dispatch into separated values of `name` and `suffix` based on input value. I didn't not get anything succeed and Its been struggling for me lately. How do I fix this problem? What would be the best practice or a proper way to achieve "U" (update) part inside reducer and dispatcher? Your help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the update case, I'd recommend mapping through your existing items:

- If the mapped item has the same id as the updated one, then replace it
- Keep the existing item otherwise

Here's the code:

```
case 'UPDATE_CATEGORY':
  return state.map(item => {
    if (item.id === action.id) {
      return {...item, name: action.name, suffix: action.suffix };
    }
    return item;
  });
```

The part where you initialise your state is missing. I'm assuming it's something like this:

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState({name: '',  suffix: ''})
```

The `handleSubmit` function receives a single parameter (event), you need to use the values from your state:

```
// remove the extra parameters
const handleSubmit = (e /*, name, suffix */) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch({
        type: 'UPDATE_CATEGORY',
        id: inputValue.id,
        name: inputValue.name,
        suffix: inputValue.suffix,
    });
};
```

[Codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-crud-52n78)

Comment: Thank you for replying... I tried your method, apparent it did not work.  Did i have my dispatcher set up correctly  `dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_CATEGORY',  id: item.id, name: item.name, suffix: item.suffix });` ?

Comment: Some parts are missing from your code snippet: where you declare the ```inputValue``` and ```setInputValue```. But you're using these later on, so I've update my answer: the ```dispatch``` uses the values from the local state.

Comment: Still struggling after making some change in dispatcher, No update changes after submit. Maybe click on this [link to view code inside codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/goofy-burnell-ip5tr) will give you some idea the way I set it up. Perhaps you could find something missing from there.

Comment: ```id``` was still missing from the action payload. Added line ```id: inputValue.id,``` to ```dispatch``` call parameters. I've forked and updated the Codesandbox example you provided.

Comment: I see, this makes sense. Now its working! Thank you for your time, truly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

```
case 'UPDATE_CATEGORY':
   let update_obj = state.find( obj => obj.id === action.id);
   update_obj['name'] = action.name;
   update_obj['suffix'] = action.suffix;

   return [...state, update_obj]
```

If I am not mistaken, this should return the original state, along with the specific element updated

Or you can do:

```
const newArr = state.map( obj => {
  if obj.id === action.id{
     obj['name'] = action.name;
     obj['suffix'] = action.suffix;
  }
  return obj
  });
return newArr;
```

Comment: This could work, I will keep that mind in the future. Thank you for sharing.